# Rclone and S3 SPaces: How to remove files older than X from my remote s3 space?

Tags: 20.04, mysql, backup

I'm learning to use rclone in order to create backups for my application, I store these backups into my DigitalOcean Space (S3), this is the line I use to backup my sql database.

```
rclone copy "${database}-${datestring}.sql.gz" dospace:dospace/sql-backups
```

Works great, now **I'd like to know how to remove from my space, .sql backups older than ONE YEAR**

**Also for backing up user images for my app I'm planning to use this sync instead of copy, does that make more sense?
What I do is move images from the space hey are stored to a backup space**

```
rclone sync dospace:dospace/images dospace-backup:dospace-backup/images
```

Is that a good practice? Can you guys give me a few tips to using rclone for making backups of my ubuntu server?